# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables, react-table, react-data-table-component

i was trying the basic example of react-tables, and i got this error
"Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."
whereas I have exported the component.
here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import ReactTable from "react-table";  

const data = [{
    name: 'Ayaan',
    age: 26
}, {
    name: 'Ahana',
    age: 22
}, {
    name: 'Peter',
    age: 40
}, {
    name: 'Virat',
    age: 30
}, {
    name: 'Rohit',
    age: 32
}, {
    name: 'Dhoni',
    age: 37
}]

const columns = [{
    Header: 'Name',
    accessor: 'name'
}, {
    Header: 'Age',
    accessor: 'age'
}]

export default class TableTry extends Component {  
    render() {  
        return (  
            <div>  
                <ReactTable  
                    data={data}  
                    columns={columns}  

                />  
            </div>        
        )       
    }  
}
```

and here are the version details:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-table": "^7.0.4"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import ReactTable from "react-table";` is for [version 6](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6) of `react-table`, version 7 is not supported. You can use [react-table-6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-6)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import ReactTable from "react-table-6";
import "react-table-6/react-table.css";
const data = [
  {
    name: "Ayaan",
    age: 26
  },
  {
    name: "Ahana",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Peter",
    age: 40
  },
  {
    name: "Virat",
    age: 30
  },
  {
    name: "Rohit",
    age: 32
  },
  {
    name: "Dhoni",
    age: 37
  }
];
const columns = [
  {
    Header: "Name",
    accessor: "name"
  },
  {
    Header: "Age",
    accessor: "age"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactTable data={data} columns={columns} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

check here [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-bose-ni5mt)

Comment: How is 7 different?

Comment: ReactTable version7 is completely different as it is based on reactHooks
Check this link out - https://thewidlarzgroup.com/react-table-7/#pagination---usepagingation-hook